# Remote connection between two android Devices

Tags: android

I am just thinking how a teamviewer kinda application can be developed for the Android devices.

I just want to know the ways of implementing an application through which I can access **Another Android device** including all the events that happens on the host device(just like TeamViewer for desktop). I know that there is TeamViewer app for Android but I just want to try myself

I heard about some protocols like RDP/VNC but those are for desktop sharing. But is there any protocol for Android device sharing ? (Note: I would like to do it using intenet)

If there is anything wrong in the way I ask please let me know..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remote the interface of 3rd party applications running on a secured (what consumers normally have) device.  Such a device does not permit you to capture the screen display of other applications* or to inject touch/key events into them.

If you want to confine your work to unsecured (ie, "rooted") devices, there are a number of open source projects out there, and probably some compiled and ready-to-install apps as well.  And if you only want the android device to be the computer the user holds (and not the one being remote-operated) then that is possible.

(* a few vendors have shipped devices not entirely following Google's recommendations, on which it is possible for an application to grab the screen display, however they still don't permit injecting input events)

Comment: but there was an application called androidscreencast which does the same for desktop and device and that is for everything.. I mean no concept of security there !! how can the same be done in unsecured ones according to you ? can you be a bit clear please ?, thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to know how a remote connection can be established between two android devices..